# Better way to code this code snippet (copy paste)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to improve upon a VBA code created through recording a macro. Can the code below be optimized (I was informed to avoid .Select as much as possible)? The code itself works fine for me though.

```
    Sheets("DataExport").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("Analysis").Select
    Range("BX1:CI4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DataExport").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using `Select`. You could try the following code:

```vb
    Dim ws_data As Worksheet, ws_analysis As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    
    Set ws_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataExport")
    Set ws_analysis = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis")
    With ws_data
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).ClearContents
        ws_analysis.Range("BX1:CI4").Copy
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you the following answer/advise:

As far as your first piece of code is concerned, this can be re-written as:

```
Sheets("DataExport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
```

As far as the second piece of code is concerned (about the copying), I'd like to refer you to [this very complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). (I might give you the answer but I believe you'd better try to create it, based on this URL. If you have any issues, please edit your question, we'll have another look).

Comment: Thank you very much, the link provided is indeed informative and gave me the answers.

Comment: @Sad22: Your welcome. In case my answer helped you find the answer, please indicate this answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Second part:

```vb
With Sheets("Analysis").Range("BX1:CI4")
    Sheets("DataExport").Range("B1").Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
End With
```